# GetFeatureInformation button won't retrieve data

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo, ext-js, heron-mapping-client

I'm using HERON with Google maps, everything seems to be fine except for the `getFeatureInformation`. I don't know if it's the layer sequence or the proxy setup or something else, because during the process of my research I saw a couple of people mentioning those to be the problem at times.

Attached is my code:

```
Ext.namespace("Heron");
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi";  
Heron.layout = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    id: 'hr-container-main',
    layout: 'border',  
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',  
            id: 'hr-menu-left-container',
            layout: 'accordion',
            region : "west",
            width: 240,
            collapsible: true,
            split   : true,
            border: false,
            items: [
                { xtype: 'hr_layertreepanel',
                    contextMenu: [
                        { xtype: 'hr_layernodemenulayerinfo' },
                        { xtype: 'hr_layernodemenuzoomextent' },
                        { xtype: 'hr_layernodemenuopacityslider'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        { xtype: 'panel',   
          id: 'hr-map-and-info-container',
          layout: 'border',
          region: 'center',
          width: '100%',
          collapsible: true,
          split : true,
          border: false,
          items: [
                { xtype: 'hr_mappanel',
                  id: 'hr-map',
                  region: 'center',
                  collapsible : false,
                  border: false,
                  hropts: {
                        settings :
                        { projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                          displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                          units: 'm',
                          maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(1247348.5486233, -4263307.2348958,                                             4260801.9513187, -2448386.4355452),
                          center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(3094067.15174,-2937583.41650).transform(
                                ([3094067.15174,-2937583.41650], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                          maxResolution: 'auto',
                          xy_precision: 5,
                          zoom: 12,
                          theme: null
                        },
                        layers : [
                            new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),
                            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                                    "World Cities (OpenGeo)",
                                    'http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?',
                                    {layers: "cities", transparent: true, format: 'image/png'},
                                    {singleTile: true, opacity: 0.9, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true,
                                        noLegend: false, featureInfoFormat: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml', transitionEffect: 'resize'
                                     }
                            ),

                            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                                    "South Africa",
                                    "http://gis.lib.virginia.edu:8080/geoserver/South_Africa/wms", { 
                                    layers: 'South_Africa:ponet_polygon',
                                    transparent: true
                                }, {

                                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                                    singleTile: true, 
                                    opacity: 0.9, 
                                    isBaseLayer: false, 
                                    visibility: true, 
                                    noLegend: false, 
                                    featureInfoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml"
                                }),

                                new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                                        "Outer layer",
                                        "http://gis.lib.virginia.edu:8080/geoserver/South_Africa/wms", {
                                        layers: 'South_Africa:popoint_point',
                                        transparent: true 
                                    }, {
                                        singleTile: true, 
                                        opacity: 0.9, 
                                        isBaseLayer: false,
                                        visibility: true,
                                        noLegend: false,
                                        featureInfoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml"
                                    }),

                                 new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Madibeng Road Network",
                                            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
                                                layers: "Madibeng_LM_RoadNetwork0",
                                                transparent: true,
                                                format: "image/gif"
                                            }, {
                                                buffer: 0,
                                                featureInfoFormat: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'
                                            }),
                                            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Dihlabeng Place Names",
                                            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
                                                layers: "Dihlabeng_Place_Names",
                                                transparent: true,
                                                format: "image/gif"
                                            }, {
                                                buffer: 0,
                                                featureInfoFormat: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'
                                            }),

                            // google layers dropped download
                                    new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                                    "Google Satellite",
                                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, visibility: true},
                                    {singleTile: false, buffer: 0, isBaseLayer: false}

                            ),

                            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                                    "Google Streets", // the default
                                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, visibility: false},
                                    {singleTile: false, buffer: 0, isBaseLayer: false}
                            ),

                            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                                    "Google Terrain",
                                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, visibility: false},
                                    {singleTile: false, buffer: 0, isBaseLayer: false}
                            ),
                            //end of google

                        ],
                        toolbar: [
                                {type: "featureinfo", options: {
                                pressed: true,
                                getfeatureControl:{
                                    hover:true,
                                    drillDown:false,
                                    maxFeatuures:1

                                },
                                popupWindow: {
                                    width: 360,
                                    height: 200,
                                    featureInfoPanel: {
                                        showTopToolbar: true,
                                        //displayPanels: ['Table'],
                                        displayPanels: ['Grid'],

                                        // Should column-names be capitalized? Default true.
                                        columnCapitalize: true,

                                        // Export to download file. Option values are 'CSV', 'XLS', default is no export (results in no export menu).
                                        exportFormats: ['CSV', 'XLS', 'GMLv2', 'Shapefile', 'GeoJSON', 'WellKnownText'],
                                        // Export to download file. Option values are 'CSV', 'XLS', default is no export (results in no export menu).
                                        // exportFormats: ['CSV', 'XLS'],
                                        maxFeatures: 10
                                    }
                                }
                            }},
                            {type: "-"} ,
                            {type: "pan"},
                            {type: "zoomin"},
                            {type: "zoomout"},
                            {type: "zoomvisible"}, 
                            {type: "-"} ,
                            {type: "zoomprevious"},
                            {type: "zoomnext"},
                            {type: "-"},
                            {type: "measurelength", options: {geodesic: true}},
                            {type: "measurearea", options: {geodesic: true}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: the first thing to do is open up the network tab in debugging (where this is depends on your browser - try F12) and see what request is being sent when you click on the button, then try that in the browser.

Comment: @iant thanks for the advice but I'm not sure how to read through this page, however I thought to show you snapshots of what I press the button http://imgur.com/a/GUQ7a#0 and after I press where I want to retrieve the feature information http://imgur.com/a/GUQ7a#1

Comment: scroll down that page and you should see urls that contain getFeatureInfo - try clicking on those and chosing open in new tab

Comment: I can't find that here or else I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/debugging-javascript.html for a guide to get yyou started

Comment: @spk578 can you please help me with this one.

Comment: we are not really in the position to help you learn how to program in javascript - this site is about geography and GIS questions

Comment: @iant but the question is about GIS, I didn't realize it has javascript implications. I was just not sure what the problem was since I'm a nood, anyhow it's OK.

Comment: your question is entirely a javascript question, the fact that GIS is making the call is irrelevant. So you need to learn how to atleast do minimal javascript debugging to be able to find out what is going on before we can help

Comment: Well, like I said I didn't realize because what I'm getting is this message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)" next to the URL of the layer I'm trying to retrieve data from.   I was hoping to get help on this aspect.

Comment: It almost certainly means that your proxy isn't working but until you find the request and show that it is working there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26148/discussion-between-el-dix-and-iant).

Comment: There is too much code above, you should simplify to just show the code that is giving you the error for the GetFeatureInfo issue, not replicate the whole map functionality.